# Improving Home For Sale

Tags: flooring

I am selling my house. Although my basement does not flood we had a pipe break and it ruined the floors, walls etc. We have the structure up to install drywall or paneling on the walls. Which do you recommend and why.
Thank You
Regina Miller

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This is really a decorating or real estate value question, and so is off-topic here.

Comment: I agree with Daniel. It's also impossible to say with out all sorts of more information...budgets...local market...your house's style...demand for basements...etc. Best to ask your realtor this question.

Answer (score 2):

Paneling (at least what is usually meant in the current era by paneling) will give it that retro 1970's basement conversion feel. So I would advise avoiding that like the plague.

*But it skates rather close to being an off-topic decorating question.*

You might just leave it where it's at - someone who wants a workshop down there would want a different wall than someone thinking home theater.

Comment: Unless you live in a hipster-gentrified area, in which case a 70's interior could bring big $$ (I say this half jokingly but half seriously)

Comment: I would never underestimate basements.  I can add 30k to a house by framing out the basement to three rooms and adding drywall, 40k if I add a bathroom (for mid range houses).  So my crew gets extra work and I am up 20k after costs on almost every basement.

Answer (score 0):

I think the blank slate look would win me over the most. That's assuming there are no walls already framed out.  Assuming there are, drywall would be a winner, though if you decide to go with paneling I suggest painting it white. I recently purchased a home that has an addition that is paneled, but painted white. It opens up the room quite a bit as well as gives it a clean, coastal look.